# How do I print message to stderr in Go?

Tags: linux, go

I want to print some logs for debugging and testing, but existing logs are massive, so I want to print my own logs to stderr:

```
go run main.go 1>/dev/null
```

So that I can just see my own logs.

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try writing to FD 2?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `log` package by [default](http://golang.org/src/log/log.go#L58) prints to `os.Stderr`.

You can also use [`os.Stderr`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-variables) directly (it's an `os.File`).

Comment: Just to show some code: `log.Println("Failed.")` will print to stderr.

Answer (score 31):

There are multiple methods to send a message to `stderr`:

1. Creating a new [`log.Logger`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger):

   ```
   l := log.New(os.Stderr, "", 1)
   l.Println("log message")
   ```
2. Using [`fmt.Fprintf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf):

   ```
   fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "log message: %s", str)
   ```
3. Directly writing to `os.Stderr` using [`os.Stderr.WriteString`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.WriteString):

   ```
   os.Stderr.WriteString("log message")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux systems, you could also use [syslog(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) facilities. By default, the underlying [openlog(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/openlog.3.html) does not go to stderr, but this can be changed.

See Go package [log/syslog](https://golang.org/pkg/log/syslog/).