# How can I print to Stderr in Go without using log

Tags: error-handling, go

How can I write a message to Stderr without using `log`?

[A comment in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934859/how-to-print-message-to-stderr-in-go) shows how to do it with `log`: `log.Println("Message")`, but what if I don't want a timestamp?

Is the following good Go?

`os.Stderr.WriteString("Message")`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The Go builtin functions `print` and `println` print to stderr. So if you simply want to output some text to stderr you can do

```
package main

func main() {
    println("Hello stderr!")
}
```

Documentation: https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#print

Comment: Good tip! However, it says: "Print is useful for bootstrapping and debugging; **it is not guaranteed to stay in the language.**" so maybe not for long-term projects?

Comment: IMO, `print` and `println` are used for debugging.

Comment: Indeed the documents say that `println` prints to STDERR. Though, **it seems not printing to STDERR by default**. Throwing away the STDERR by `go run ./main.go 2>/dev/null 3>/dev/null`, I'm still getting a "Hello stderr!" message. Which means that it's printing to STDOUT. I think @julienc [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29721532/8367711) `fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Hello stderr!")` should be the accepted answer too.

Comment: Note to self: be careful about using `| grep 'DEBUG'` in combination with `2>`. Somehow I still get the stderr output on my terminal while using `2>`.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat each command in a group of piped command can independently output to `stderr`. Consider this instead: `somecommand 2>/dev/null |grep 'DEBUG' 2>/dev/null` in order to send `grep` errors to `/dev/null` in addition to `somecommand` errors

Comment: @KEINOS what OS do you use to get println in stdout? I am trying to reproduce to understand it better, however it still prints into stderr

Comment: @TarasMatsyk **My bad!  I DO GET the STDERR with `println`**. I think I was confused. The reason was that I ran the code on the Docker container. `docker run --rm -it -v "$(pwd)":/root/src golang:alpine go run /root/src/main.go 2>/dev/null`. This will print the error message since the container prints to STDOUT the "outputs inside the container".

Comment: Haha, I didn't even know these exist )

Comment: After some experimentation, I found that `go test` redirects stderr to stdout behind the scenes. So any usage of stderr will not show up during `go test`.

Answer (score 143):

If you don't want timestamps, just create a new [`log.Logger`](http://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger) with `flag` set to `0`:

```
l := log.New(os.Stderr, "", 0)
l.Println("log msg")
```

**EDIT:**

> Is the following good Go?
>
> ```
> os.Stderr.WriteString("Message")
> ```

This is acceptable, and you can also use [`fmt.Fprintf`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf) and friends to get formatted output:

```
fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "number of foo: %d", nFoo)
```

Comment: If you're going to use stderr to actually log things, use a logger. Otherwise, a simple `os.Stderr.WriteString` will suffice, IMO.

Comment: Best answer. Although, my personal preference is using fmt.Fprintf or fmt.Fprintln. If you're doing this many places in your program, maybe wrap it in a function then you can easily change stderr to stdout or whatever writer you want.

Answer (score 134):

Using the `fmt` package, you can choose to write to `stderr` this way:

```
import "fmt"
import "os"

func main() {
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "hello world")
}
```

Answer (score 26):

[`os.Stderr`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Stderr) is an [`io.Writer`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer), so you can use it in any function which accepts an `io.Writer`. Here are a few examples:

```
str := "Message"
fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, str)
io.WriteString(os.Stderr, str)
io.Copy(os.Stderr, bytes.NewBufferString(str))
os.Stderr.Write([]byte(str))
```

It all depends on how exactly you have the string you want to print (i.e. if you want to format it first, if you have it as an [`io.Reader`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader), if you have it as a byte slice...). And there can be a lot more ways.

Answer (score 7):

By default the logger flags are set to `Ldate | Ltime`. You can change the logger format to any of the following (from the [golang log documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#pkg-constants)):

```
Ldate         = 1 << iota     // the date in the local time zone: 2009/01/23
Ltime                         // the time in the local time zone: 01:23:23
Lmicroseconds                 // microsecond resolution: 01:23:23.123123.  assumes Ltime.
Llongfile                     // full file name and line number: /a/b/c/d.go:23
Lshortfile                    // final file name element and line number: d.go:23. overrides Llongfile
LUTC                          // if Ldate or Ltime is set, use UTC rather than the local time zone
LstdFlags     = Ldate | Ltime // initial values for the standard logger
```

For example, flags Ldate | Ltime (or LstdFlags) produce,

```
2009/01/23 01:23:23 message
```

While flags Ldate | Ltime | Lmicroseconds | Llongfile produce,

```
2009/01/23 01:23:23.123123 /a/b/c/d.go:23: message
```

You can also set the default logger to not print anything by setting the flag to 0:

```
log.SetFlags(0)
```

Comment: how are you supposed to use these flags?

Answer (score -3):

use SetOutput function, set output stream to os.Stdout

```
import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

func init() {
    log.SetOutput(os.Stdout)
}

func main() {
    log.Println("Gene Story SNP File Storage Server Started.")
}
```